# Произношение йэ, йы

Tags: произношение

Почему в произношении буква **'е'** слышится скорее как **йы**, а не как **йэ**? Или это только я так слышу?
Йысть/Йэсть (**Есть**),
Йыль/Йэль (**Ель**)

Добавляю запись с обеими вариантами произношения
[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brcp9u5llbmpq7q/Aug%2024%2C%2013.14%E2%80%8B.aac?dl=0)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду слова **есть, ель**?

Comment: Да, это как пример

Comment: Мне не слышится в этих словах никакого Ы. Более того, сочетание ЙЫ не очень-то просто произнести: Й требует узкого просвета под мягким нёбом, а Ы - наоборот. Без ударения еще допустимо произнести Е как Ы: **шептать, танцевать**, но под ударением (**есть, ель**) должно звучать четкое Е. Возможно, у вас получится предоставить нам аудиозапись, как вы произносите эти слова?

Comment: @SergeySlepov добавил запись к вопросу. Мне как раз было трудно йэ произносить на запись) а йы нормально

Comment: **шептать** и **танцевать** другой случай, так как там нету звука **й**

Answer (score 1):

На вашей записи я слышу две группы из 5 слов, где произношение первого гласного различается: в первой группе он более открытый, почти как я, яль, ясть... в международной транскрипции ([IPA](https://www.ipachart.com/)) это звук [ɛ], а во второй группе - более естественный е (IPA [e]). Оба звука довольно далеки от [ы] (IPA [ɨ]).